# Meaning of error message "Heap corruption detected"

Tags: c, heap-memory

I'm working with Visual Studio C.

I found that the programs report errors in a strange way when I write outside the range of an allocated vector.

This first program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int* qwe = (int*)calloc(100, sizeof(int));
  for (int j = 0; j < 210; j++) qwe[j] = 1; // Wrong range!
  printf("Hi!");
  for (int k=0;k<1000;k++) \\ just to spend time!
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) 
      sin(cos(j));
}
```

simply stops before "Hi!". This one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int* qwe = (int*)calloc(100, sizeof(int));
  int* asd = (int*)calloc(100, sizeof(int));
  for (int j = 0; j < 210; j++) qwe[j] = 1;
  printf("Hi!");
  for (int k=0;k<1000;k++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) 
      sin(cos(j));
}
```

ends without reporting any problem, although the difference is just that I allocated an extra array. And finally this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int* qwe = (int*)calloc(100, sizeof(int));
  int* asd = (int*)calloc(100, sizeof(int));
  for (int j = 0; j < 210; j++) qwe[j] = 1;
  printf("Hi!");
  for (int k=0;k<1000;k++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) 
      sin(cos(j));
  free(qwe);
  free(asd);
}
```

runs but, at the end (after the useless cycles), it gives me this message:

[image: error message]

Of course, I know how to avoid the problem: just, pay attention to the index range. But my question is: what is exactly the meaning of the error message? What is the "normal block"? Why "after" and not "before"? What is exactly the displayed address? Why the message is issued only at the "free" command and not when the "heap corruption" takes place?

Comment: It's the result of the system detecting that you have written beyond the memory allocation. You allocated for 100 items and trying to write 210.

Comment: Please, carefully read the question. I asked something else. I'm asking what is the meaning of the numbers reported in the error message.

Comment: Oh, in that case, don't expect any predictable result from undefined behaviour. It isn't guaranteed to cause damage. The example with a second buffer, might have been damage free when the system allocated more memory than was requested for each, so the writing happened to be within the allocation.

Comment: You're asking what the MSVC debug library developers had in mind when conveying this dialog? The debug library keeps track of memory allocations, including putting guard areas on either side. When being free'd this dialog is telling you at least one of those guards was detected as breached.

Comment: This can explain the address (exceeded that write-guard). But this still does not answer the whole question: what is the "normal block" and why "after". And, just out of curiosity: why the test is done after freeing the vector?

Comment: The system doesn't check anything at the time of the write, apart from exception errors detected by the hardware. There is no superviser quietly checking the end guards while you write to memory. It's detected in the `free` call.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how it is done. Is this documented anywhere? Anything that I can read about this? And: any hint about the "normal block" and the "after"?

Comment: Please see [CRT Debug Heap Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2022) which discusses it, and "normal blocks".

Answer (score 2):

_NORMAL_BLOCK tells you what kind of allocation it was, there are also _CRT_BLOCK (internal to the library), _CLIENT_BLOCK (also allocated by user code but with some special handling available), and _FREE_BLOCK.

It's "after" and not "before" due to the order that corruption is check for. Since overruns are more likely than under that is checked for first.

The reason it waits until free is called is simply because it only checks during allocation and de-allocation calls. It would make programs run enormously slower if there were a system in place that checked every write to make sure it is in bounds.